# Is there a Four-Per-Em Space character - but as NO-BREAK Space?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, character

I had a look around the web but did not find something suitable, so here is my question:

**Is there a Four-Per-Em Space character - but as NO-BREAK Space?**

Comment: it is used to seperate two characters i.e. "29° C", but only 1/4 of a em wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I can find in the Unicode character database is

`U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`

Comment: that is what i figured out too. well, was still hoping to be able to find a NO-BREAK Four-Per-Em Space character